# Intent to open web page/app in standalone mode

Tags: android, google-chrome

I have a web app with a web manifest. Users can add my web app to the home screen of their Android devices; when they do, the app opens in the "standalone" mode, meaning browser Chrome such as address bar are not shown. Good so far.

From a native Android app, I want to start my web app in the standalone mode (irrespective of whether the user has a home screen shortcut for my web app). Is this doable, maybe by adding some extras to the regular intent that opens the web app in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this is currently possible.